# Ollydbg and hundreds of events under QT GUI

Tags: ollydbg

I'm trying to debug an application that uses QT GUI library. The problem is that I can't even start debugging as ollydbg seems to be processing ~1k events per second where in stack trace I see all of them running inside QT. The application has very fancy GUI (blending, custom window and buttons etc) and perhaps that is what hangs the debugger as it tries to process all this. Eventually it bluescreens. Can I somehow force olly to skip or ignore these events?

Comment: It bluescreens?? Could you post the crashdump?

Comment: It's weird. I tried to open memory.dmp in BlueScreenView (freeware) and it shows nothing. No raw data, no drivers. Just basic information like termination string (CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION) bug check code and size. Is it possible that dumps are corrupted?

Comment: WinDbg is the preferred way to review a crashdump.

Comment: Alright. If the application happens to crash the system, it might use some rootkit to prevent memory analysis and whatnot. Anyway, I tried with different QT application and result is the same (yet, perhaps it's not QT fault but coincidence). 100-400 events per second and I can't use the application since it's "stuck" (I can't even maximize it or open popup menu -- when right clicking the icon on task bar).

Comment: Perhaps some extensive applications really do process lot of events, even in the background. How can I debug such applications? This is what the stack trace shows (it hits new events all the time, very quickly) http://cap.ring0.cc/c7234a2d45e076d62aecf28a74e95c29.png

Comment: By default, OllyDbg only monitors debug events, which shouldn't noticeably slow down the execution. Are you using logging breakpoints and/or tracing?

Comment: Thats the weird thing I've been wondering about too. Why does my stack trace get messed up even though I didn't ask to log the trace (it just happens) and I believe my settings are default. I also tried with 2.0 version that I recently downloaded (before I could even open options) and the result is the same. I browsed through options several times but I couldn't find thing I can (un)tick to fix this issue.

Comment: That bugcheck indicates that some process such as `smss.exe` or `winlogon.exe` was shot down (probably by the debugger?).

Comment: Hey. I assume that could be shot down by the rootkit which triggered when the debugger tried to look into it. But that's not the case at the moment. I was trying to attach to other process (that doesn't kill the machine) but I have the same problem as with the previous one. That is, hundreds events per second which "hangs" the debugged program (stack trace, almost, repeats itself as shown on the screen in the previous comments).

Comment: I finally found out how to load applications quickly but I don't know what's causing this behaviour! Apparently if I pause the application, discard the hit trace, resume, wait couple seconds until it'll slow down again, pause, discard, resume over and over then I can load any large binary in less than a minute! Why is that so?! Sometimes I'm getting "Invalidating non-flushed cache!" error though when doing that.